# loading d3.csv of 3.8 MB file fails on some systems

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Its about this app:
http://mgd-togo.com/crisisNet/SyriaSocialMedia/CrisisNet-Syria.html

On startup I load in a 3.8 MB csv file by calling

```
d3.csv('data/Data.csv', function (error, personData) { ...
```

This works on most systems, however on others the browser window crashes. Also, when opened in "Anonymous mode" it tends to work better -> is it a cache/ memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading those 3.8MB csv(?), then process them multiple times.

3.8MB is not that much data, but processing it actually crashes my browser.

You are sending JSON objects as CSV rows, then go trough all of them.
My suggestion is :

1)Use JSON instead of CSV, since you data is mostly JSON already.

2) if you still absolutely need to process the entire dataset (instead of having it already properly formatted from the server), try to implement some lazy loading (multiple requests).

Comment: Exactly, processing, not loading, crashes the browser! 
But I load the resulting JSON data into a global variable which is then used in the processing of the code.
So you suggest loading in a JSON file instead?

Comment: My suggestion is to receive data that is already properly formatted (if it comes from the database, that would be easy), and reduce client-side processing.

Comment: That's true, unfortunately not an option here. But d3.json() (JSON-> JSON) should be lighter than d3.csv() (D3->JSON) right?

Comment: If you have to loop through the object and process the same way as the csv, I doubt that it will make any difference.